# Convert List<Long> to Map<Long, Long> that counts occurrences

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm playing around with Java 8 and I know that this must be possible by reading the documentation, I just cannot find out how to do it.

I have the following working code:

```
    long factorProduct = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, maxFactor)
            .filter(this::isOptimalFactor)
            .reduce((i, j) -> i * j)
            .getAsLong();
    List<Long> primeFactors = primeFactors(factorProduct);
```

Important part is that I have a `List<Long>` that *may* have duplicates on some `Long` numbers.

Now I want to convert it to a `Map<Long, Long>` with as key the element and as value the occurences.

I thought that:

```
    Map<Long, Long> primeFactorCount = primeFactors.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.counting());
```

would work, but it doesn't. I looked up the examples [in the java.util.stream.Collectors documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

How do I need to use these features?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to group the elements, you have to use `groupingBy`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<Long, Long> primeFactorCount = primeFactors.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(p -> p, counting()));
```

Comment: I've tried it before, but was giving an error, turns out I had forgotten to automaticaly import java.util.Map.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you could use the following for the prime factors list and the prime factor count.  A `Bag` is basically a `Map<K, Integer>`.

```
MutableList<Long> primeFactors = this.primeFactors(factorProduct); 
Bag<Long> primeFactorCount = primeFactors.toBag();
```

Use a [`FastList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/mutable/FastList.html) in the primeFactors method above.

In the case of Eclipse Collections we have primitive Lists and Bags, so you will not need to box any results.

```
LongList primeFactors = this.primeFactors(factorProduct);   
LongBag primeFactorCount = primeFactors.toBag();
```

Use a [`LongArrayList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/mutable/primitive/LongArrayList.html) instead in the primeFactors method above.

**Note:** I am committer for Eclipse Collections.